# How to name text file at a certain directory?

Tags: c++

Ok thanks for the answer Wug! I changed my code but now it's complaining about:

> no matching function for call to
>
> > std::basic_ofstream::basic_ofstream(std::basic_string)

I'm not sure it makes any difference but i'll just post all of my code it's not that much so far.
I'll try to keep it cleaner from now on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   /*Introduction*/
SetConsoleTitle("Journal");

string action, prom0, filename, filepath;
filepath = "C:\\Users\\-\\Desktop\\Projects\\Journal Project\\Logs\\";
cout << "Hi and welcome to Journal! \nHere you can write down your day.\nWrite help for";
cout << "more \nType command to start: ";
/*Choose Action*/
cin >> action;
if (action == "new")
{system("cls");
/*Make new Journal file*/
cout << "Filename: ";
getline(cin, filename);
 mkdir("C:\\Users\\-\\Desktop\\Projects\\Journal Project\\Logs");
ofstream journallogs(filepath + filename);
journallogs.close();
}
else {
cout << "Wrong command\n";
};
return 0;}
```

Comment: Are you clear on the difference between `std::string` and `char[]`?

Comment: No i'm not aware of the exact differences between the two. I would be happy to receive any advise you have!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things wrong.  The first is what the compiler's complaining about:

```
ofstream journallogs("C:\\Users\\-\\Desktop\\Projects\\Journal Project\\Logs\\" + getline(cin, filename), ios::out);
```

`std::getline(istream&, string&)` returns `istream&`, and you can't add `char *` to `istream`. I recommend taking a look at the [documentation for `getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), which might help you understand better how you're supposed to use it.  Here's an example anyway:

```
string filepath = "C:\\Users\\-\\Desktop\\Projects\\Journal Project\\Logs\\";
string filename;
getline(cin, filename);
ofstream journallogs(filepath + filename);
```

The second problem is that you're reading from `cin` into `filename` before calling `getline()`.  When you call `getline()`, any contents of `filename` are dropped, so you'll effectively trim the first word off of your filename, which probably isn't what you want.  To  fix that, remove the extraneous `cin >> filename;`

Note: indentation is important and helps you read your own code.  Put forth the effort to keep your code looking nice.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn this:

1. Start small and simple.

   Add complexity a little at a time.

   Test at every step.

   develop new functionality in isolation.

   *Never add to code that doesn't work.*

For the rest, I don't use Windows, so I can't be certain my code will work there, but the approach will.

You are trying to 1) get a filename from the user, 2) modify it and then 3) use it to open a file; we will **develop these three things in isolation.**

Getting a filename from the user. Civilized filenames do not contain whitespace, so they can be read with `cin`, but if you want to allow whitespace you can use `getline` instead. Either way, **test it.**

Modifying the filename. Write code that assigns a value to the filename, just as it does to the path-- do *not* get the filename from the user, it slows down your testing and is not proper **isolation**. Now try to append them. If you try `filepath + filename`, you may get a compiler error. Here's where you must understand the difference between `std::string` and `char[]`. A `char[]` is an array of `char`, and it (usually) contains a null-terminated sequence of characters; you must read up on arrays and pointers. It is a primitive type, and you cannot simply concatenate two of them with '+', you must use something like `strcat`, which is dangerous if you haven't done your homework on arrays. On the other hand, `std::string` is more sophisticated, and can handle '+' and many other operations. If you have a `std::string x` and you decide you want a `char[]` after all, you can get one like so: `x.c_str()`.

Opening the file. If I remember right, the `ofstream` constructor can take a `char[]`, but *not* a `std::string`. Test this with a hard-coded string (isolation!).

Once you have these three components working independently, you can hook them together.